# Flow and error control

Tags: tcp, udp

TCP is able to do flow and error control, is it a resulting consequence of using virtual circuit to send pacquets ?
Would it be possible to do error end flow control in datagram mode ? For e.g with UDP ?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

No, it's the other way around. TCP creates a virtual circuit, it is not using one: IP is connectionless. Doing error corection and flow control would be possible in the application using UDP, but what would be the point? If you require those, it would make more sense to use a protocol which already provides it, like TCP.